# How can I streem a YouTube video in a python frame?

Tags: python, video, youtube

Hello I'm tiring to make a python program that will take in a YouTube URL as a variable and then will open a frame with predetermined height and width with the video playing in it.

At first I tried doing this buy using the markdown module and writing that to an HTML file and opening it, but couldn't get markdown to work. (maybe i have the lib installed wrong)

Is there a better way to get this to work, or a lib that is better suited to do this.

Any help would be nice and as always if you need any more information I'd be glad to help in any way I can.